# How do I connect two apps

Tags: c++, windows, process, ipc

I am considering building an app in C++ that will be parsing text from the web and create some statistical results. These results I want to be fed in an external app in real time. The external app (to whose code I have no access, but can ask for a - paid - custom made addition) will then need some code to read and use these results.

I am wondering what would be the best way to interconnect the two apps, in terms of speed and ease of implementation. I am considering :

```
 disk I/O (slow) 

 a Windows service  

 a DLL  

 a web service  

 a web page
```

Perhaps I am missing a better solution ? Thank you.

```
Update : there is an additional need to know how long a data request may take at worst.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of IPC mechanisms to choose from from (sockets, shared memory, pipes, ...). I guess the "best choice" will depend to a large extend on how the other application is structured aka. how much your custom extension will cost you.

I don't know much of your environment but it might be worthwhile to have a look at boost.interprocess:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Answer (score 5):

- Sockets?
- Shared Memory?
- RAM Disk?
- TCP/IP?
- Windows Messages?
- Command line arguments (of the other application)?

What methods does the other application have to support receiving data?

Comment: AFAIK the other app only receives data from the keyboard. Command-line arguments will not do the trick because the sums need to be fed constantly in real time and the external app must be running already.

Answer (score 3):

A windows service would be sensible but would still need to communicate with the other app, this is called IPC, approaches on windows are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx), Named Pipes are simple & flexible, File Mapping is powerfull.

An alternative would be to stick a database in the middle?

Comment: Good points. It also made me realise that I need to have some control over the speed of the communication process. For instance, a Windows message might be queued and take time to reach its recipient. I will update the o.p. to add this restriction too.
I wonder what overhead a db would impose...

Comment: A database has some disk read/write stuff and will probably be slow.